Meaning of the method of characteristics at crossing points of characteristic lines
Given a system of linear PDE's of first order such as $w^1_t + cw^1_x = 0,w^2_t - cw^2_x =0,$ one usually uses the method of characteristics to find the solution $(w^1(x,t),w^2(x,t))$ on each point of the plane $(x,t)$ given initial conditions at the point $(t,x) = (0,0).$ Along a characteristic line defined by $dx/dt = c$ and thus $x(t) = ct+a,$ the solution $w^1$ along the one characteristic and $w^2$ along the other characteristic are constant. The point $a$ on the $x$ axis is called anchor point. I guess these two constants must be the same. In particular, given any point $(x,t)$ on the $t-x$ diagram, two characteristic lines will cross. They will have different anchor points. Thus, the solution to the system above on that point must not be the same, since they belong to different characteristic lines. Does that mean that solutions are not unique ? What I am missing here ? I will appreciate your answer.

Does this discussion address your Question?  (Search for "intersect" on that page.  It'll jump you to the Inviscid Burgers' Equation section.)

It does. Thanks.

@EricTowers. Is this equation,$u_t + kuu_x =0$, also an inviscid Burger equation for k constant? Can one use the characteristic method used in the discussion you mentioned above?

Well, it's an inviscid Burgers' equation with a parametric flux function.  I would expect to find qualitatively similar solutions for different choices of $k$.  If you want to move past intersecting characteristics (having differing solutions), you may have to reformulate -- your system has singularities so does not have smooth enough solutions.
